# Matlab: Calling functions in a different file

Tags: matlab

I have a function, `loggmm.m`, that I would like to call from a different file `blp.m`. Both files are in the same directory. `blp.m` initializes some global variables that `loggmm.m` should use everytime I call it.

Even though I declare them as global variables (`global var1 var2 var3`) in the first line of my `loggmm.m` function, the `loggmm.m` function is not able to recognize the variables that I initialize in my `blp.m` file.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: are they also declared `global` in `blp.m`? Is there a call to `clear all` that happens along the way?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code, without seeing the code we can only guess what's wrong.